# ListView contents not visible on back navigate

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a ListView in a fragment and it works fine when I open the fragment.
However when I'm navigating backwards to the fragment, the contents are invisible.

The data is there but the view is not rendered properly. Strangest still, when I set a breakpoint on the onPause method the views are rendered and everything works fine. Any ideas?

```
public void getFriendsCallback(ArrayList<User> friends) {
    adapter.clear();
    adapter.addAll(friends);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    // The friends are invisible after back button
    super.onResume();
    refreshFriends();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add the listview in the fragment you need to save the fragment state in the system stack.
When you invoke your Fragment in an activity do it this way.(Use Android Support Library)

```
    ListFragClass frag=new ListFragClass();
    FragmentTransaction ft=getSupportFragmentManager();
    ft.add(R.id.listfrag,frag).beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Here `R.id.listfrag` is the fragment in XML. `ListFragClass` is your `Fragment` containing the `ListView`.

Comment: I am adding it to the backstack and when I navigate back I pop the backstack. I am however not using the support library, will try that.